# Anova vs wilcoxon

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, repeated-measures, data-transformation, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have collected data of 73 patients with tinnitus where 45 have received a cochlear implant (therapy 1) and 28 have received a hearing aid (therapy 2). To research the impact of these two therapies on tinnitus, I've collected data through 2 questionnaires (THI and TFI) on 3 moments (baseline, follow-up 1 and follow-up 2).

First, I wanted to see if there was a statistically significant change in the THI scores at the 3 moments. The data of the THI scores of the total group was not normal distributed so I've used the Friedman test, followed by the Wilcoxon signed-rank test with a Bonferroni correction.

Secondly, I wanted to look at the 2 groups separately. The data of THI scores in the group with therapy 1 was also not normally distributed so I've used the same tests as above.
The data of THI scores in the group with therapy 2 was normally distributed. So, I've used the repeated-measures ANOVA. This showed a non statistically different change in THI scores in time. I expected a change in time in this group as well, and if I looked at the differences with a paired-samples t test there was a significant statistical difference between baseline and follow-up 1.

Is it correct to use the repeated-measures ANOVA for the normally distributed groups and the Wilcoxon signed-rank test for the not normally distributed groups? Do I need a more uniform analysis by transforming the data and use the repeated-measures ANOVA on all the groups? Or is it better to use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test as the data mostly is not normally distributed?

Comment: It's a good idea not to jump to quickly from design to analysis issues.  Ask whether the design is suitable for the question.  I gather it is not a randomized design.  Then you are very likely to have massive confounding by indication - so massive that analysis may not be warranted, or requiring you to faithfully collect many strong confounding variables to be adjusted for.

Comment: No it is not a randomized design. How do I know which are the strong confounding variables and how can I adjust for them?

Comment: It is necessary to survey say 5 expert audiologists who do not know about your data to ask them each what are the main factors used for selection for implant vs aid.